# Effect on acidity of benzene due to electron withdrawing groups

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> With respect to the compounds **I**–**V**, choose the correct statement(s).
>
> [image: List of compounds]
>
> 1. Compound **II** becomes more acidic when it has a $\ce{-NO2}$ substituent.
> 2. The acidity of compounds follows the order **I** > **IV** > **V** > **II** > **III**.
> 3. The conjugate base of compound **IV** is aromatic.
> 4. The acidity of compound **I** is due to delocalization in the conjugate base.

I am not able to decide about the first statement properly. I compared the acidity by considering the conjugate base, which is the same (benzyne) even if $\ce{NO2}$ group is added.

However, the solution says that it will increase acidity because of being an electron withdrawing group.

Comment: Do you really think conjugate base of II is benzyne?

Answer (score -1):

Both the predictions are good. The $\ce{NO2}$ will actually be an effective electron withdrawing group, and the lost of that $\ce{H}$ will stabilize the compound (if there is and $\ce{NO2}$ on it). It is also important to rescue, that both effects will be stronger just on *para* or *ortho* position. You can make the different structures to check it.

Comment: It is talking about the acidity of the compound, so ortho para don't matter here, the acidity of the compound in general matters.

Comment: @PK Objection. The relative position of the nitro group to the deprotonated carbon influences the acidity of the compound.  Draw the deprotonated form and count the mesomeric formulae possible for each of them and you find _o_ and _p_ differ from the _m_-pattern.  It isn't limited to benzoic acids, although often the [ortho effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho_effect#First_ortho_effect:_ortho_effect_in_substituted_benzoic_acid) is taught on them as example.

Comment: @Buttonwood The deprotonated form holds the extra electron (i.e. the negative charge) in an $\ce{sp^3}$ orbital which is parallel to the plane, whereas the pi system is perpendicular to the plane. So they can't interact with each other and conjugation is not a factor here. Simple inductive effect would predict ortho > meta >para in order of high to low stabilization of the anion.

Comment: Indeed... the answer is wrong (-1 from me) and @SRMaiti is absolutely spot on.